# If value in one column is null give another value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> name  age  grade  pass
0   Dana  23    95    yes
1   Emaa  24          yes
2   Don   25    99    yes
3 Daniela 24    85    yes
4   Fred  21          yes
```

I want to create a condition so if column grade is null, the value in column pass will be no :

```
>>> name  age  grade  pass
0   Dana  23    95    yes
1   Emaa  24          no
2   Don   25    99    yes
3 Daniela 24    85    yes
4   Fred  21          no
```

I have tried this way:

```
if df['grade'].isna():
    df['pass']='no'
```

but I get error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

how can I get the expected results? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `np.where` or `mask`

```
df['pass'] = df['pass'].mask(df['grade'].isna(), 'no')
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this Ben, could you please do let me know how you created `df` from samples? I tried to copy and use `read_clipboard` but then its not taking space in between and last field its making as `NaN`, any guidance will be appreciated here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have not create the dataframe ~ , just based on his expected output and the solution should be pretty obviously ~